API Development - Use SQL joins or cached tables?
This is a theoretical question; me and my colleagues discuss this so I want to hear you thoughts as well.
Background: we want to develop a web based ticket system.
Because of that, there will be a large list of ticket objects and different parameters that may differ. For example one ticket will have a category, a priority, a customer, a user etc.
Those ticket parameters are most of the time quite short lists, for example there will be 15 categories, 5 priorities and so on.
We want to use Microsoft SQL Server, C# Web API and Vue.js as frontend.
For example, if I want to have the list of all current opened tickets:
My colleagues say, that the following is the easiest way to go:
join all the required tables in SQL into one view and parse them as one large JSON array from the API to the vue.js.
But I say that there might be performance issues and it would be quite better doing one query for all categories, one for all priorities etc. and save / cache them, then retrieve only the raw ticket data and use the cached values for display. I think transporting all the displayed values in the large JSON is way to much overheat and is not necessary. As this data may growth, for example, it would send the category name "user management" 500 times, instead of sending only the id.
Do you think that has a large performance issue, or is this not the case because all JSON is transferred as text, so it does not matter if its an int or an string.

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil." You can speculate about what might be a performance issue, or you can implement a proof of concept and test it. You might be trying to fix an issue that will never exist. Or might exist, but will remain small enough that it's tolerable. Part of software engineering is implementing prototype code so you can test it and then know whether it works or not, and with what performance behavior. Then decide what optimization is needed.

A big payload is a big payload. You could make an infinite scroll so that way you only load 20 tickets at a time or something. If you need to search, you could have some advanced already-cached in advance features like Solr/Elasticsearch/Algolia.
Depends also on the amount of DOM elements in each ticket but yeah, performance issues might arise, especially on mid-end mobile devices.
The fact that you might need to build it from scratch too might be heavy, having something already rendered ahead of time (if possible) so that way you only need to display the HTML might also help with the performance because you gonna skip the JSON overhead (aka: having straight HTML is lighter on user's devices).
You could even use tools like MarkoJS so that way you get it even faster thanks to progressive rendering for example.
So overall, lots of things could be done to optimize the performance. It all depends on your skills/bandwidth and constraints.
Having some sluggish load times might also be fine if it's not critical regarding other priorities. But this is more of an internal decision to take.
TLDR: yes, optimize for your users if you can.
